# Emitting event from structural directive to parent component does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

As a follow up to question: [Emit event from Directive to Parent element : Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962701/emit-event-from-directive-to-parent-element-angular2)

It looks like when a structural directive emits an event, the parent component does not receive it.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[appWidget]' })
export class WidgetDirective implements OnInit{
@Output() wdgInit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Input() set appWidget (wdg: any) {
    //display stuff
}
ngOnInit {
   this.wdgInit.emit();
}
```

widget.component.html:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let wdg of widgets">      
  <div *appTwitterWidget="wdg" >
  <ng-container>
```

widgetContainer.component.html:

```
 <app-widget [widgets]="widgetList" (wdgInit)="containerDoSomthing()"></app-widget>
```

In this case I find containerDoSomthing() never getting called.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's possible. The issue is that current Angular 5.2.6 still doesn't support `@Output` binding for structural directives if used with the sugared asterisk (*) syntax (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12121)) like in the question.

To make it work you have to transform it to de-sugarized  form ([see here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix)) like this:

```
<ng-template [appWidget]="wdg" (wdgInit)="containerDoSomthing($event)"></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to add an EventEmitter to a structural directive, simply because the native element that the directive references, is always a comment!

It is probably due to this fact that, an event never gets generated in the DOM in the first place... This is not a problem with attribute directives though, as they sit on a proper DOM element.